# How to upload files to MediaWiki APIs in Rust?

Tags: file, rust, upload, mediawiki, reqwest

I'm attempting to upload video files to Dustloop, a mediawiki page for ArcSys games, and I've managed to get all the way to acquiring a CSRF token to be able to upload, but I'm struggling on the last part. I believe I have correctly done everything else, But I'm not able to get the file part correctly.

```rs
async fn upload_file(client: &mut reqwest::Client, csrf_token: String) {
    let mut params = HashMap::new();
    params.insert("action", "upload");
    params.insert("filename", "maria-artemis-test.webm");
    params.insert("comment", "API test file.");
    params.insert("token", csrf_token.as_str());
    params.insert("format", "json");
    let url = reqwest::Url::parse("https://dustloop.com/wiki/api.php").unwrap();

    let file: Vec<u8> = fs::read("output.webm").unwrap();
    let file_part = Part::bytes(file).file_name("output.webm").mime_str("video/webm").unwrap();
    let form = Form::new().part("video", file_part);

    let response = client.post(url).form(&params).header(reqwest::header::CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart/form-data").multipart(form).send().await.unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", response.headers());
    println!("{}", response.text().await.unwrap());
}
```

this is my current code so far, taken from [simmons/reqwest-upload-example.rs](https://gist.github.com/simmons/6c2e6eb3ade5bfcb962250603dd667cf), but this doesnt seem to function for me.

The [mediawiki API docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Upload) (same API as dustloop) has a python example, and I think ive gotten as close as I can

Any assistance on getting this to correctly upload files? Currently it just dumps the API documentation page back to me, not even responding with a json response (although if I remove `.multipart`, it does respond with JSON, so theres something there going wrong I think). Everything else should be fine, it is just the multipart process that goes wrong.